Reaction of potassium iodide in alkali medium with ozone
My textbook mentions the following reaction:
$$\ce{KI + 3O3 (alk.) -> KIO3 + 3O2}$$
$$\ce{KI + 4O3 (alk.) -> KIO4 + 4O2}$$
What should I infer from this? Does $\ce{KI}$ disproportionate in alkali medium with ozone? Because I searched a bit on the internet and did not find any relevant answer.
And why are the 2 reactions not written combined as
$$\ce{2KI + 7O3 (alk.) -> KIO3 + KIO4 + 7O2}$$
EDIT:
As a user pointed out that both the reactions can occur but it depends on conditions such as concentration temperature or pressure etc. Which one will, can someone give more details about that. Want conditions to form which product?

Related but in aqueous medium; https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80662/why-does-ozone-disproportionate-on-reaction-with-potassium-iodide

@NilayGhosh but that us a different reactions the products are KI and KOH Not KIO3 and KIO4. Is this reaction correct?

As I said, they are related but not same reaction. The medium is different leading to different products.

@NilayGhosh then does KI disproportionate in alkali? And why is it not written as a single reaction?

Both reactions occur, but not at the same rate; they are alternate paths. In some cases KIO3 is the main product, in some, KIO4. It would depend on initial conditions -- concentrations, temperature, catalysts, etc.

@DrMoishePippik Could you please provide more info like at what conditions will they form?

I would rather expect sub reactions KI -> KIO3 -> KIO4, with conditions determining the extent the second reaction occurs.

The question reminds of the poem about five blind sages who went out to touch an elephant for the first time and decided to explore it with their hands Full parable here? ; someone touched the elephant's side, and claimed the elephant is like a big wall, someone touched the trunk and called it like a big snake. And the discussions and arguments went on. The poem says all of them were partly right but all of them were essentially wrong.
In the same way, all your three equations are partially right but they are all wrong overall. Chemical reactions which proceed as written are called quantitative reactions just like neutralization reaction of NaOH and HCl will form salt and water. Nothing more and nothing less. It will proceed quantitatively.
With these oxidation reactions with ozone, you will get mixtures of products in most cases, depending how the gas and the solution are introduced in alkaline KI solution. The balanced equation does not say how to carry out the reaction. Your textbook is representing an idealized situation, or in a better way, this is what the author wanted to make. She/he knew the product and the reactants and balanced the equation.
The third equation is also not fully true because we will not know if the products (iodate and periodate) will be formed in a 1:1 ratio. The reason that the reaction is not a single step reaction. I think iodine is liberated first followed by further disproportionation.
The ozone and iodide ion in an acidic medium do react quantitatively under certain conditions by liberating iodine. This is how air is analyzed for ozone pollution.

Thank you very much but as you pointed out none of the reactions give the complete image. So could you provide the reaction mechanism and intermediate steps?

I really do not know the exact mechanism at this moment and finding mechanism and intermediate steps of a complex reaction like this is like someone's 5 years of research (PhD work). However, I am sure people must have investigated it and published their findings.

Rollbacking to the original draft as the new edits make it a wall of texts by merging the paragraphs. Please don't approve unnecessary edits from anonymous edits.
